# Concurrent Creation Event

Tags: hibernate, jboss, second-level-cache

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0 GA together with Hibernate and I'm now trying to enable the second level cache.  I've added the following properties to my Hibernate configuration.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.MultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.jbc2.query.localonly" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="my_prefix" />
```

And I've annotated entities that I expect to change infrequently with the following:

```
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
```

This is based on my understanding of the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/hibernate-caching/3.3/en-US/html_single/index.html).

The application successfully deploys with no scary looking messages (e.g. WARN or ERROR messages in the log stream). For a short period of time I see caching working (I'm using Hibernate statistics to see this), but after a short while I get stack traces of the form (even when logged on as a single user with no remote access whatsoever):

> "Transaction attempted to create
>   MYCLASS anew.  It has already been
>   created since this transaction
>   started, by another (possibly remote)
>   transaction.  We have a concurrent
>   creation event"

Following by a giant stack trace which eventually traces back to a named query that I have made which has the following form:

```
SELECT x FROM X WHERE x.deleted = false
```

The named query has no additional annotations for caching.

Any advice on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No sure that it will help, but I would try to play with locking and isolation settings of the cache.

Comment: This did help - switched to using pessimistic-entity rather than mvcc-entity and all is well again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions first:

1. Is this exception propagated to your application? I mean, are you affected by this, or you are just concerned about the message in the log?
2. Are all of your entities annotated with Transactional strategy, or only a few of them?
3. Does your query retrieves eagerly fetched objects of another class?

I would say that the best thing you could do now is to enable DEBUG (or maybe even TRACE) logging for the Cache operations: `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=debug` This will tell you exactly what Hibernate is doing. I *suspect* that Hibernate is trying to put an object to the cache, and doing it again once it sees the same object during the same session (maybe as part of another object's tree). There was a timestamp issue for Query Cache some time ago, and the same problem might be occurring here. For instance:

```
Object A#1
 -- Object B#1

Object A#2
 -- Object B#1
```

But again, it's a bit hard to predict what the solution is without knowing what the problem would be. And I'm afraid that only Hibernate's log can tell you what the problem really is.

PS: this was meant to be posted as a comment, but this was just too long for it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  In answer to your questions.  1) This is propagated to the application and does cause some problems.  2) All cacheable entities are annotated in the same way, but it's only a small portion of the entities that are annotated like this.  3) There are some @ManyToOne relationships on the class that will pull in other cached objects.  I agree with your suspicion that this might cause the issue so I'll make the logging changes that you suggest and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: I altered the cache configuration to use pessimistic-entity instead of mvcc-entity and the error message went away.  Measurements show that caching is an improvement, so for the moment I'll leave it like it is.  I'm accepting this answer as the hint on hibernate caching debug tracing pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE? I read the docs a lot of times and don't know precisely what to choose, but seems to work fine for my projects. I guess the CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL is too much safe and avoid the cache performance in certain circumstances.

Comment: CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE doesn't appear to be supported for JBoss cache (at least according to this documentation - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache).  I can't use READ-ONLY because there is a slim chance that the entities will be modified.